# generated json with id path

Tags: php, json

I have the following json response which I created it using php.

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Clean Code","author":"Robert Martin","bookUrl":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/1DJybxH","imageUrl":"http:\/\/adavis.github.io\/adept-android\/images\/clean_code.jpg","displayDate":"August 11, 2008","numberOfPages":"464"},{"id":"2","title":"Effective Java","author":"Joshua Bloch","bookUrl":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/1Ku8Xel","imageUrl":"http:\/\/adavis.github.io\/adept-android\/images\/effective_java.jpg","displayDate":"May 28, 2008","numberOfPages":"346"},{"id":"3","title":"Working Effectively with Legacy Code","author":"Michael Feathers","bookUrl":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/1Jqe1PA","imageUrl":"http:\/\/adavis.github.io\/adept-android\/images\/legacy_code.jpg","displayDate":"October 2, 2004","numberOfPages":"456"},{"id":"4","title":"Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code","author":"Martin Fowler","bookUrl":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/1Lx4cjR","imageUrl":"http:\/\/adavis.github.io\/adept-android\/images\/refactoring.jpg","displayDate":"July 8, 1999","numberOfPages":"464"}]
```

And out of this response I have a query that returns a single book as a json object.

[url link](http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample_book.php?id=2)

So with that url,the book with id = 2 is returned.

```
{"id":"2","title":"Effective Java","author":"Joshua Bloch","bookUrl":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/1Ku8Xel","imageUrl":"http:\/\/adavis.github.io\/adept-android\/images\/effective_java.jpg","displayDate":"May 28, 2008","numberOfPages":"346"}
```

However,when i don't use the id path in my url,the first book(id=1) is always returned. I am not sure if this is correct.

This is my php code.

```
<?php 
 include("init.php");
 $string="";
 $newString="";
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']); 
 $get_posts = "select * from books"; 
 if($id != '') $get_posts .= " WHERE id LIKE '%{$id}%'"; 
 $run_book = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts);     

 $string =    
 json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($run_book),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

 echo $string; 

?>
```

Any advice?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: One thing i noticed on your PHP code, when trying to query a numeric data type, please don't treat them as a string, instead use equal sign for this.

Comment: Sorry. Can you be more specific? What should I change again? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using LIKE, when working with numeric data type, use WHERE id = {$id}

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem. The url returns back the book whose id equals 1. http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample_book.php. I want to do that instead with http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample_book.php?id=1.